# Problem listening to a WAV file embedded into a beamer presentation using Adobe Reader

Tags: beamer, adobe

I have embedded a `.wav` file to a beamer presentation using `\sound` command. The wav file is sampled at 22050 Hz and has 16 bits/sample.

```
\sound[autostart, inlinesound, samplingrate=22050, bitspersample=16, encoding=Raw]{\beamerbutton{Play}}{music.wav}
```

It's impossible to listen to the file on PDF because it sounds like noise.
Any insight/help to sort this problem out is very much appreciated.

Comment: Probably the same problem as in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/pull/607 , but without further details about the pdf reader and OS just a guess....